# What is Binary (application/octet-stream) file type?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My client sent me file, suppose to be Backup file of MSAccess. They are using MSAccess as database application.

The file is around 80MB. I am expecting a backup file from them.

What I got is ***Binary (application/octet-stream)*** file type. It is neither SQL nor .BAK.

I am planning to get proper backup file from them in whatever format they have. And convert whole into MySQL format. Fortunately I have trail version of Red Gate software for 14 days that converts .BAK into SQL format.

I cannot open/use ***Binary (application/octet-stream)*** file or use it to convert into MySQL. How can I achieve proper bakcup file with ***Binary (application/octet-stream)*** file type? I would appreciate any solution to achieve my goal.

Comment: what is its current extension ?

Comment: I have received file without extension.

Comment: try giving it extension like xyz.accdb and save it .See if it works. also make sure to have the backup of the original file .

Comment: I did give extension. And its same. I am getting backup file from different part of India, unfortunately they have no knowledge of database.

Comment: its same means? did you try to open it with MS access?

Comment: @Developer I don't have MSAccess thats why I try to convert it into MySQL. The file itself is not opening foremost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103590/discussion-between-tashi-and-developer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a file exported from Heroku using the commands:

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download
```

The file was imported into my local database using:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```

See the docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).